# How to see the build events for all projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, post-build-event, build-events

I want to rebuild my entire solution, but I want to make sure that the projects have no post-build events. Is there a quick way in Visual Studio to do this? I would rather not check the properties of every single project one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use property sheets for that.

If you go to **View|Other Windows|Property Manager** you can see the property sheets for the projects in the solution. Select one project, and edit the properties that project, remove post build events, etc, then save that property sheet. Finally, from the Property Manager select a number of projects simultaneously (click while holding the shift key) and click on **Add Existing Property Sheet** then select your saved property sheet. You can verify that that property sheet has been added to all the selected projects and that it works as desired.

Comment: I should have clarified that these are c# projects, and it seems that property sheets only exist in c++ projects.